# Comma before sub clause

Tags: exam-questions

Which option is correct? It seems like all options are possible but 5. On the other hand, I didn't understand what function the comma have in the sentence. As far as I know I don't have to or  should not use comma before sub clauses if they follow main clause.

> The United Nations officially recognized the greenhouse effect in
>   1995, ----.
>
> 1. when its International Panel on Climate noted that human activity
>      had a discernible influence on global temperatures
> 2. as the economies of developing nations will grow over the next few
>          decades
> 3. if developing nations were exempted from the Kyoto Agreement
> 4. since the US government announced that it would not participate in
>          Kyoto Agreement
> 5. that the participating nations must make large and costly changes in
>          their energy systems

Comment: I would say the  first us correct.

Answer (score 1):

Three and five cannot be correct, because they use the wrong tense. The clause in the question is in the past, so we'd expect the remaining piece to either also be voiced in past tense, or include language which changes the semantic time (example: *as a result, we are starting a new study*). None of these do either of those.

From a purely grammatical perspective, one, two, and four are correct, so we cannot rely on linguistic rules to tell us which one is the right choice. The desired answer is most likely option one. Its semantics - a modifying clause supplying additional time-related information - dovetail nicely with the question's text, which is about when a specific event happened. In number two, the time span is too long for it to make sense - a decision twenty years ago based on guesses about difficult to predict information which won't happen for another twenty - and the topics don't align well. Regarding option five, it would be very strange for the UN to recognize the greenhouse effect because the US did not ratify the Kyoto treaty.

Comment: Thank you. I understood your answer except why sentence 2 cannot be answer .  In 2,  aren't  the words "as" and  " the next few decades"   enough in order to change the semantic time? For example in different context, it doesn't sound wrong to say  that  " My friend left the test book yesterday as I will study for the exam over the next  few days." or  " I bought a software as/because I will use it for a project at work over the next month " Would this kind of sentences incomplete ?

Comment: That's a good point. Using *as* in that fashion is grammatically correct. I've edited my answer.